# microwave use after cell phone heating

Tags: microwave

My daughter put a cell phone in the microwave and switched it on. The phone was heated for less than a minute at maximum temperature. There was a strong smell from the burnt phone and the microwave. Can we use the microwave again? Which steps are necessary to bring the microwave to a condition where food isn't contaminated (both from an aroma and a food safety standpoint)?

[image]

Comment: Probably can't use the phone, but was there any damage to the microwave?

Comment: How old is your daughter? (curious why she would do that)

Comment: Naturally, she chose a Samsung. Does it still work?

Comment: Whatever you do, store the damaged phone somewhere where it a) can not start a fire and b) cannot get wet.

Comment: :-) Isn't this a question to be asked on http://electronics.stackexchange.com instead? Mod's?

Comment: @Nav If you really want a mod to look at something, flag it. But [questions about kitchen equipment are totally on topic](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, there's no reason to migrate.

Comment: @Jefromi your call :) I did choose "answer" format due to the safety implications of leaving a damaged device with a  lithium battery lying around - they can literally blow up hours later. Wanted the warning to be well visible.

Comment: electronics.se is temperamental about repair questions - and the main issue here is food safety/hygiene, not repairing the electrical function of the microwave or the telephone for that matter....

Answer (score 6):

I would ventilate it well, wipe everything down and wash up the turntable. Then, when the smell has cleared (and doesn't come back when the door has been shut for a while) use it but only for covered (loosely) food at least at first.

I'd also test that it heats up a cup of water before cooking anything real in it.

Comment: When I set a potato on fire, it was *months* before the smell cleared.  (maybe if I had used it more often it'd have cleared faster ... but it smelled like burned hair)

Comment: @Joe that's also possible, and I'd give up if there wasn't dramatic improvement within a couple of days. Testing with a cup of water can be done before it clears,  and there's just a chance that the steam will help dissipate the smell. Also leaving it semi-outside (like a garden shed).

Comment: maybe also some baking soda as that's a bit abrasive and can help absorb oders

Comment: And heat some water with vinegar in it.